# Query for email not working

Tags: mysql

When I run a query for email, it returns null.

```
SELECT * FROM `cookie_auth` WHERE `email` = 'test@test.com'
```

So I inserted another row with just "test" in the email column and it works.

```
SELECT * FROM `cookie_auth` WHERE `email` = 'test'
```

Don't know if this might be any useful information but I am on Windows 8.1, the collation is armscii8_general_ci, engine is InnoDB.

Edit: Another note, the email is the primary key if that helps at all.

Edit 2: I think maybe the table is broken in some way, I've been messing around with it with cookies, hashed tokens and hashed passwords too much. My other table is querying just fine with emails. Any possible solutions to this? Is it best to just drop the table and create a new one?

Edit 3: It was the collation, I created a new table with latin_swedish_ci and email queries run fine now. Also why was there a down-vote?

Comment: how about `WHERE trim(email) = 'test@test.com'` ?

Comment: you should learn SQL Oprator first ..http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Comment: Have you inserted in the table or fetched from the table, because you have used `SELECT` statement. Clarify your post.

Comment: What do you mean by fetched? I inserted 2 rows, one with "test@test.com" in email column and another with just "test" in the email column.

Comment: I'm not sure if edited posts give notifications so I'll mention that I made an edit to the original post here.

Comment: As I mentioned in your Meta question, please add the relevant `INSERT` statements, if you do that I'll give you an upvote. And you should post an answer instead of putting the solution in your question.

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
SELECT * FROM `cookie_auth` WHERE `email` LIKE '%test@test.com%'
```

Comment: -1 you're guessing for the cause of the problem instead of asking for more information, and this would just work around a data problem instead of fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

Try with TRIM function like

```
SELECT * FROM `cookie_auth` WHERE TRIM(`email`) = 'test@test.com'
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM `cookie_auth` WHERE `email` LIKE '%test@test.com%'
```

Comment: Try my second answer which may help you

Comment: Yes I have, its not working. I also dropped and created a table with the exact same structure and email searches still don't work. I'm starting to believe it is the collation that has something to do with it. I am about to create it again using latin_swedish_ci collation, see if that works.

Comment: Fixed. It was the collation, for some reason it doesn't work with email queries. I guess it's time to go check some documentation. If, by any chance, you know the best collation for general storage could you give me a pointer?

Comment: Can you give query for creating table? So I can try that

Comment: I use phpmyadmin for table creation. The queries weren't working when I was running parameterized queries through php and had to hunt for the problem a quicker way.

Comment: I want table schema so I can help you further

Comment: Did you see my last edit? It was the collation, queries are running fine now.

Comment: -1 you're guessing for the cause of the problem instead of asking for more information, and this would just work around a data problem instead of fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

You surely need to use **TRIM()** function as

```
select * from cookie_authwhere trim(email) ='test@test.com';
```

Here is the working sql fiddle example.

[**SQLFiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7cb7c/2)

Comment: -1 you're guessing for the cause of the problem instead of asking for more information, and this would just work around a data problem instead of fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of using email alone.
If you want the exact value, please use below query

```
SELECT * FROM `cookie_auth` WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(`email`)) = 'test@test.com'
```

Comment: SQL Server does not have function which can trim leading or trailing spaces of any string. TRIM() is very popular function in many languages. SQL does have LTRIM() and RTRIM() which can trim leading and trailing spaces respectively.

Comment: User asking question about `mysql` not `SQL Server`

Comment: sorry,that was my first post.Will ensure about all these things here after.

Comment: -1 you're guessing for the cause of the problem instead of asking for more information, and this would just work around a data problem instead of fixing it.